# VSTS Windows Machine file copy robocopy not found

Tags: azure-devops, robocopy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

So we're setting up a release where we want to copy some artifacts to a target server in order to start a deploy. unfortunately when the task starts it errors out on the actual copy with the following error:

```
The term 'robocopy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

However when checking both source and target machine the robocopy command (both from Powershell and CMD.exe run perfectly and presents the default robocopy starting screen.

We're using a private build agent running windows server 2016.

I've checked PATH variables and C:\Windows\System32 is in the list and running a search on both systems gives back robocopy.exe in the same directory.

running the task on a hosted agent makes it run fine. So it definitely is a local issue, just don't see where this might be coming from.

results of echo %PATH% and robocopy on the build agent:
[image: Echo]

Results of the Release with the failing task:

[image: Release]

As requested by Shayki the task definition:

[image: TaskDef]

Comment: If you log in to that agent machine as the **user account which the build agent service is running as** - is it able to find `robocopy`?

Comment: it's running under the default NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService as suggested by VSTS itself. I'll try reconfiguring it and see what it does when i have the agent run on another account (a local admin account)

Comment: Can you upload the Task definition?

Comment: You do know that you can copy/paste text content from a command window much easier (and readably) than posting an image?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk: see edit :)

Comment: @KenWhite yeah sure but try doing that using a mobile phone RDP connection to the machine ;)

Comment: @YanSklyarenko: tried with the local admin which was configured from azure and which i use to log on to the machine and produce above screens. When starting a build it will hang indefinitely and on release it still gives the same error on robocopy. I did restart the service and reboot the machine. Also the machine is recognized by VSTS and online w/ the new credentials

Comment: Might've found a possible cause. for some (yet unknown reason) robocopy fails when it is called from admin privileges. when i open Pshell / cmd as the logged on user and type in the command it works, yet when i run pshell / cmd "ad Administrator" i am getting above mentioned error. So my best guess this has nothing to do with VSTS but rather a local issue on the build agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for some unknown reason the %PATH% variable would show C:\Windows\System32 when doing echo %PATH% however when going through the environment variables inside control panel there was no entry for it inside the PATH environment variable.

Added the C:\Windows\System32 folder back into PATH system environment Variables (and putting it on top) fixed it for us.

Comment: Adding "%SystemRoot%\system32" under System Environment PATH, fixed the problem for me as well